# The drop-down list appears at the very top of the page (after the click)

Tags: css

Here is the preview of the drop down list

[image]

Then, when I click on the dropdown to scroll the items

[image]

I think it's because I have too many items in the dropdown?

```
<div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
   <div class="col text-end">
      <!-- Marché -->
      <label for="filterForMarkets" class="form-label">Marché</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <select id="filterForMarkets" name="filterForMarkets" style="min-width: 440px" class="form-select" [(ngModel)]="search.market">
      <option value="">
         Tous les marchés 
      </option>
      <option *ngFor="let m of markets$ | async" [value]="m.marketId">
      {{ m.name }}
      </option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

If for example, I display 3 items only, I have no problem.

[image]

```
<div class="row row-cols-3 pt-3">
   <div class="col text-end">
      <!-- Marché -->
      <label for="filterForMarkets" class="form-label">Marché</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <select id="filterForMarkets" name="filterForMarkets" style="min-width: 440px" class="form-select" [(ngModel)]="search.market">
      <option value="">
         Tous les marchés 
      </option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I need my loop, is there a way in css to display my items correctly, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put size in <select ...

```
<select size="3" id="filterForMarkets" name="filterForMarkets" style="min-width: 440px" class="form-select" [(ngModel)]="search.market">
```

If didn't work just let me know.plz down votedown right away :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set a max height to your select field using CSS:

```css
select {
max-height: 180px
}
```

Either create a class and use it instead of using the select global selector but using the global selector will just handle all your select fields which is good too so, You decide!